# d3 zoom behavior. Increasing the scale in small increments

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3 zoom behavior, for linear scale, how can I gradually increase the zoom. I use it like

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

If I understand correctly, the chart will zoom up to 10x. Is it like, each double click will zoom it 1x times, till it reaches 10x? How can I make it even finer step like, 1, 1.2x, 1.4x,..

Thanks.

Comment: My first thoughts were in the direction of applying some vanilla transition but there is such thing as [d3.interpolateZoom](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) which appears to be an interesting option.

Answer (score 2):

The zoom level increases as a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). That is, each time you click, it doubles -- 1, 2, 4, etc. The default interaction doesn't allow you to have finer steps, but you can easily do this in your handler code -- there's nothing requiring you to zoom in exactly the same steps as the zoom behaviour's scale value. That is, for a zoom level of 2 you could set the zoom factor to 1.2, for 4 to 1.4 etc.

For finer control in general, you may also want to consider having another input element on the page (e.g. an input box for the zoom level or a slider).